# How to make sure that conditional containers are conditional after conversion from edi to xml using MapForce?

Tags: xml, edi, map-force

this is my first question here, so here it goes:

I am working on MapForce mapping which converts EDI files to XML. I have documentation that says that specific containers should be conditional or repetitive (if exists value, create subvalues, etc.). Thing is that I have to check whether these requirements are really met in all cases.

What I am doing now - manually changing input and checking output, if it does the job. However, this method is messy, with huge potential for human errors and takes long time as I have many files.

Do you have any ideas how to check this faster?

Thank you in advance!